# Flask, html and javascript desktop app

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I want to build a desktop application using python, html and javascript. So far i have followed the tuts on flask and have a hello world working example. What should i do now to make it working? how do the html files "talk" to the python scripts below them?

here is my code so far :

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/hello/')
@app.route('/hello/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('hello.html', name=name)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return redirect(url_for('init'))

@app.route('/init/')
def init():
    css = url_for('static', filename='zaab.css')
    return render_template('init.html', csse=css)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: The HTML files never "talk" to the Python scripts. Python (via Flask) will use Jinja2 to render HTML files using whatever information you pass to render_template(). You should complete the tutorial here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/tutorial/introduction/ Things will make more sense afterward.

Comment: ok that makes sense but how can i pass data then? eg. pass some data from a form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML forms just as you normally would in your Jinja templates - then in your handler you use the following:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for, render_template, redirect
from flask import request # <-- add this

# ... snip setup code ...

# We need to specify the methods that we accept
@app.route("/test-post", methods=["GET","POST"])
def test_post():
    # method tells us if the user submitted the form
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.name
        email = request.form.email
    return render_template("form_page.html", name=name, email=email)
```

If you wanted to use `GET` instaed of `POST` to submit the form you would just check `request.args` rather than `request.form` (See [`flask.Request`'s documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request) for more information).  If you are going to be doing much with forms though, I recommend checking out the excellent [WTForms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) project and the [Flask-WTForms extension](http://packages.python.org/Flask-WTF/).

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer, i'm new in flask and jinja so i want to know if i have to install ninja besides flask

Comment: @MpampinosHolmens - if you run `pip install Flask` (assuming you have pip installed and available on your `PATH`) then Flask will be installed along with its dependencies (Jinja2 and Werkzeug).